# Grails update/rerender layout at runtime

Tags: grails, layout, spring-security

The situation is that I have a layout `application.gsp` that defines the layout for all the pages except the login page. Inside the layout is a header that should display the name of the current logged in user (Spring Security plugin). The problem is that if the user just registers or uses oAuth for the first time (same as registering) then when he logs in he will see and empty spot instead of a username because the layout was rendered **before** the username was available. If he logs out/logs in again he will of course see his username.

P.S. Moving the header outside of the layout is not an option, because it will cause massive code duplication.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security Core Plugin?

Comment: You've said that moving the header outside the layout is not an option, but would it be possible to use a g:include just to display the logged in user which could hit a controller to get the login name if it exists, and render it?

Comment: Can't you forward the user from the authentication action to e.g. home page action after they have logged in?  The username will then be available when the view is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question for future generations trying to solve the same problem.
The trick is in using a **decorator design pattern** and the badly documented **g:pageProperty** gsp tag.

*views/layouts/application.gsp*:

```
....
<li class="dropdown menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                           data-toggle="dropdown"><g:pageProperty name="page.username"/></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>Preferences</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="${resource(file: 'j_spring_security_logout')}"
                                   class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
....
```

*views/index.gsp:*

```
....
<body>
    <content tag="username">
        <g:username username="${username}"/>
    </content>
....
```

*taglib/UsernameTagLib.groovy:*

```
class UsernameTagLib {
def springSecurityService

/**
 * Check if the username is already available, else inject newly created username into the layout
 *
 * @attr username REQUIRED that was received from the newly registered user
 */
def username = { attrs ->
    String currentUsername = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()?.username
    if (currentUsername) {
        out << currentUsername
    } else {
        out << attrs.username
    }
  }
}
```

The newly created username is passed to *views/index.gsp* when the user is finished through the whole oAuth process.

*controllers/OauthCallBackController.groovy*

```
....
    def facebook() {
        Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]
        if (facebookAccessToken) {
            String username = oauthCallBackService.facebook(facebookAccessToken)
            render view: '/index', model: [username: username]
        } else failure()
    }
....
```

Basically the username travels upwards until it reaches the layout, which allows me to use the username in the layout header and propogate it on all the pages that need the layout.

Comment: Did you have to add identical <content> tags to every single gsp that uses that layout?

Comment: @EdJ unfortunately it's been so long ago that I don't remember anymore, haven't used Grails since then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Spring Security Core plugin`, you can `reauthenticate` user in your controller.

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username
```

Comment: This is the way how I authenticate the users, but it is not relevant to the issue of the layout rendering before the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with **[SecurityTagLib](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/)** helper of Spring Security Core.

In your **application.gsp** you can have:

```
 ...
<sec:ifLoggedIn>

 <!-- Display user field with sec:loggedInUserInfo tag -->
 Welcome Back <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="fullName"/>

 <!-- Check if user have all specified privileges -->
 <sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
  You've ROLE_ADMIN AND ROLE_SUPERVISOR privileges.
 </sec:ifAllGranted>

 <!-- Check if user have at least one specified privileges -->
 <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
  You've ROLE_ADMIN OR ROLE_SUPERVISOR privileges.
 </sec:ifAnyGranted>

</sec:ifLoggedIn>

<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>

 It's public content, anonymous user.

</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
 ...
```

You can also use: `<sec:ifNotGranted roles="ROLE_USER"></sec:ifNotGranted>`